# How lazy Data structure works

Tags: apache-spark

Having some doubts on `action and transformation` in Spark.

I'm using spark API from last couple of months. (`Learned`) Spark api has a power which says that it wont load any data into memory until any action is taken to store final transformed data somewhere. Is it correct understanding ?

More refined defination:

Spark will create a DAG(Directed Acyclic Graph) using the `applied operation, source RDD and function used for transformation`. And it will keep on building this graph using the references till you apply any action operation on the last lined up RDD. That is why the transformation in Spark are lazy.

The moment action is triggered (For example writing to file), data will start loading into memory from source and then transforming and finally writing into file. Is it correct meaning of `action` ? OR Action is something when driver program submits `transformation and action graph` to master and then  master sends respected `data and code` to different worker nodes to execute ?  Which one is correct understanding ?

Have Read online posts, but not cleared.

Answer (score 1):

You right, spark won`t do anything untill certain action will be taken (e.g write).

Every transformation will return a new RDD contains it`s DAG and when you submit an action, spark will execute the DAG (If you use dataset it`ll make optimizations too).

Action is a method that submit the DAG as said (writing into file/foreach and more actions).

The driver is response to parallize the work, keep a live on executors and send them tasks.

Comment: So sending split data + code using driver program from master to executors considered as Action ..?

Comment: Nope, action is a method on RDD/DS that submit the DAG.

Comment: But DAG is submitted by driver program to master ..! Isn’t it ..?

Comment: It depend on the cluster manager you are using, im assuming you talking about standalone cluster, so the master's responsability is to allocate resources.(And also track on all the running spark's application on the cluster).